# How to log queries which taking longer than XXXXms in Slick

Tags: sql, performance, scala, slick

Ideally I want to add additional logback appender to write all slow queries into `slow_queries.log` file.

I had a look through official documentation as well as SO and I can't find easy configurable way to do so.

Any help (even links to some github code) would be highly appreciated.